# How do I get the latest commit files of a submodule in Github Actions so I can use it in my build process?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, github-actions

Recently I have created a React website that is dependent on data coming from another repository. So I have added this remote repository as a submodule in my own repository on Github. The files of this submodule are used when I build the website. Locally, I currently use the following flow to incorporate the remote files into my build:

```bash
cd public/remote-data
git pull
cd ../..
yarn build
```

Et voila, the files of the submodule are baked into my build.

Now, I would like to automate this process in Github Actions so that every commit triggers a new build with the most recent data from the remote repository. To do that, I have tried to use the [Checkout multiple repos (nested)](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-nested) feature from the checkout action, in combination with some yarn commands to install the depencies and to build the website:

```yaml
- name: Checkout tools repo
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    repository: remote-org/remote-data
    path: public/remote-data
- uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
  with:
    cmd: install
- uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
  with:
    cmd: build
```

However, when I try to do this, it seems that the whole context of Github Actions shifts to the remote repository. As a result the following `yarn install` and `yarn build` commands do not work as expected as they need the proper folder context to work properly.

My question then is: Using Github Actions, how do I use the most recent version of a remote repository in the build process of my own repository?

PS. If you feel using the checkout action is not the way to go, feel free to suggest another method to reach the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following step to checkout the repository with submodules:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    # Whether to checkout submodules: `true` to checkout submodules or `recursive` to
    # recursively checkout submodules.
    submodules: true
```

Source: https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage